# we have recently updated the Neptune Engine to version 1.1.1.Along with that we updated the gremlin to version 3.5.3.Now we are facing websocket error

Tags: node.js, websocket, gremlin, amazon-neptune

Initially we faced some issues related to child graph traversal , once we resolved that we are facing the below issue ,
ERROR

```
WebSocket is not open: readyState 2 (CLOSING)
    at WebSocket.send (/var/task/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:329:19)
    at /var/task/node_modules/gremlin/lib/driver/connection.js:184:20
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at /var/task/node_modules/gremlin/lib/driver/connection.js:166:9
```

this is how we are establishing a connection

```
const DriverRemoteConnection = gremlin.driver.DriverRemoteConnection;
   const Graph = gremlin.structure.Graph;
   if(typeof dc ==='undefined')
   {
  var dc =  new       DriverRemoteConnection("wss://"+process.env.NEPTUNE_HOST+":"+process.env.NEPTUNE_PORT+"/gremlin",{pingEnabled:false});
}
```

This never happened  before , we could this error only after upgrade is there something needs to be changed related to connection establishment ??are we missing some configuration or properties that needs to be declared externally ?

Comment: How is the application connecting to Neptune, for example, is this from a Lambda Function in the same VPC as the Neptune cluster?  It's hard to tell from the error message what might be going on. Are you able to send any queries, or does it not even get that far? Are you able to reach the cluster `/status` API from the same location? If you are able to open an AWS support case, a support engineer may be able to verify that the request is reaching the cluster.

Comment: Just checking back in on this one - were you able to get your code working? If not are you able to open a support case?